# Tkinter shows all pages at once rather than one by one

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been trying to make a data entry application, that has pages to enter new categories, horses, etc. I have different pages for each but the problem is they are all called at once rather than one by one upon request. When I run it I get a window with all the things I have packed and the buttons are not responding to anything.

Here is my code:

```
class App(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MainMenu, AddData, AddHorse, AddCategory):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.pack()

        self.show_frame(MainMenu)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class MainMenu(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        add_category_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Add Category",
                                 command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AddCategory))
        add_horse_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Add Horse",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AddHorse))
        add_data_btn = tk.Button(self, text="Add Data",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(AddData))

        add_category_btn.pack()
        add_horse_btn.pack()
        add_data_btn.pack()

class AddCategory(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Add Category')
        label.pack()
        home_button = tk.Button(self, text='Go Home',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainMenu))
        home_button.pack()


class AddHorse(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Add Horse')
        label.pack()
        home_button = tk.Button(self, text='Go Home',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainMenu))
        home_button.pack()


class AddData(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text='Add Data')
        label.pack()
        home_button = tk.Button(self, text='Go Home',
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainMenu))
        home_button.pack()

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you copied uses `grid`, not `pack` for the frames. This code only works with `grid` for the pages.